# Html and javascript video preview player

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

please I have a phpmyadmin database where a list of video names are stored, I also have a file where these videos are stored, so I am outputting this videos to the front end with a function in php called `MYSQLI_FETCH_ASSOC` when these data are gotten from the server with the function, a JavaScript function I created will append it with a div tag.
And I also have a function that obverse when the first video data is success, then the function sends a response to the server and the server bring another data from the database.

So my problem is how can I preview part of the video in the video tag.
By default after the page finish loading, the video tag becomes black in color, until  i click on it to play.
So I want it to show a part of the video after the page have finish loading, just as Facebook, Twitter , Instagram.

The video tag

So how can I make the video to show part of the video data ???

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the `poster` attribute to the video tag. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video).

```
<video width="470" height="255" poster="placeholder.png" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <object data="video.mp4" width="470" height="255">
    <embed src="video.swf" width="470" height="255">
    </object>
</video>
```

**EDIT: How to get thumbnail from video**
You can display your first video frame as thumbnail by adding `preload="metadata"` to your video tag and the second of the first frame `#t=0.5` to your video source:

```
<video width="470" height="255" poster="placeholder.png" controls preload="metadata">
    <source src="video.mp4#t=0.5" type="video/mp4">        
</video>
```

Or... if the video is in the same domain you can use [Popcorn.capture.js](https://github.com/rwaldron/popcorn.capture) which will allow you to create posters from any frame of your video.

Or... you can use canvas to capture the thumbnail as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47447082/3990896) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794798/3990896) explain.

Comment: i dont need poster, i want the original video content to show, i have already try poster

Comment: What do you mean by original video? What you see first in every social media is just a image from the video (poster/thumbnail) and only when you hover it or press play the actual video is loaded. [Example from Twitter](https://imgur.com/uHDBszc).

Comment: What you may be looking for is some kind of automation to get a thumbnail image from a video but that is an entirely different question.

Comment: So how can I get a thumbnail from a video ???

Comment: See if my edit to the answer helps.